# setsockopt returns errno=2

Tags: c, sockets

Im creating an UDP  socket (centos 6), which i want to send broadcast message. Everything works, creating socket works - socket(..) returns value=25, but:

```
int val = 1;
      if (setsockopt(a, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &val, sizeof(val)) < 1){
          debug("setsockoopt failed with errno: %d, socket %d", errno, a);
      }
```

setsockopt sets errno to value = 2. Communictaion works, im sending udp packet to x.x.x.255 host, and all my apps recives it, but im wondering from where that errno came (errno=2=no such file or directory)

best regards

Comment: You need to be specific as to the OS / version.

Comment: try char val = '1' and sizeof(char)
this is what beej says http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#broadcast he says: '//char broadcast = '1'; // if that doesn't work, try this'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Upon successful completion, the value 0 is returned; otherwise the
>   value -1 is returned and the global variable errno is set to indicate the
>   error.

That's from the [setsockopt manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/setsockopt/) returns 0 on success, so it's just your condition that's wrong.  If there was no error, errno's value is not relevant, and that's why here you get a rather absurd value.

```
if (setsockopt(a, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &val, sizeof(val)) != 0){
```

is what you need.